# Filtering Sharepoint Person/group column with contains does not work

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to filter a Sharepoint list and show only those rows to logged in user if the Person/Group  column (with Allow Multiple set to True) has the logged in user's name.

I tried to filter using the contains option but receiving below error. Can someone suggest how this can be resolved?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the filter setting for "is equal to" and `[Me]`. I found that this works fine in people fields that have multiple people selected.

Answer (score 0):

'Contains' filter can only for searching a string anywhere within a column that holds **Text or Note field type** values. I think it cannot be used for user/group column.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/contains-element-query

You may consider using below filter:

1. [Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/includes-element-query)
2. [Eq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/eq-element-query)

BR